# Pgsql Stored Procedures or Rails classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, stored-procedures

This is more to do with maintenance issues for a Rails app. Currently , it has a lot of stored procedures (Postgres -pgsql) and I 'm wondering if I should do away with them and translate them into Rails classes. Performance-wise would rails classes be a better idea than pgsql stored procs? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a problem to solve? If not, don't spend time in creating new ones.

Stored procedures can be (much) faster, but it all depends on what you're doing and how you're doing it. It all depends...

pl/pgsql is very powerfull language and when it does what it should do, I wouldn't spend time in refactoring all the code into any other language. Just a waist of time.

Comment: Code maintenance is cumbersome with stored functions. And there are slight inconsistencies when there is some mapping happening between the Rails app,the procs and the db. I just wanted to know if stored procs work well with Rails (because I read somethere they don't that well) . Thanks Frank.